# is "NOT EXISTS" bad SQL practice?

Tags: sql, sql-server, coding-style

In SQL Server, using "NOT EXISTS" in queries are considered bad practice and I've heard that microsoft code reviews test for NOT EXISTS and flag these as warnings. Why is NOT EXISTS considered bad practice and that join operators are preferred over NOT EXISTS?

Comment: Apart from this question not really being objectively answerable, where did you ever hear such a thing?

Comment: `is “NOT EXISTS” bad SQL practice?` NO

Comment: I don't think this qualifies as `not constructive`...Best practices are valid to ask about

Comment: @Lukas - I thought this was common knowledge.  It may ve extremely bad practice because for the query engine to check the condition it may have to do a full table scan, which naturally is not optimal on large tables. Of course in some circumstances it's not really avoidable, but it should be coded around wherever possible.

Comment: @Cruachan - I disagree. Not exists CAN be expensive but it's not cut and dry.  It short circuits still, so in cases where you expect it to filter a lot of records it can be quite fast.

Comment: "not constructive" on Stack Overflow means that it cannot be answered objectively and will lead to lengthy debates, like this one here...: `This question is not a good fit to our Q&A format. We expect answers to generally involve facts, references, or specific expertise; this question will likely solicit opinion, debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion.`

Comment: @Lukas - point taken, but I still think this could be answered pretty objectively.  SQL is tougher than say C# for things like this, since there are very few absolutes with databases

Comment: @JNK, OK "bad practice" may be over egging it a little, but certainly it's the kind of thing that should flag up a mental warning to check your code. It wouldn't be unknown for example for it to cause issues going from development to production if the production database table is significantly larger. Myself I'd be inclined to have a warning against its use in any coding practice document.

Comment: FYI - I heard it from someone (who seem to know what he's talking about) that NOT EXISTS is bad practice and that joins are preferred over NOT EXISTS. If I want to find out if this is actually industry/microsoft standards, how can I rephrase the question so that it's more constructive?

Comment: @Cruachan - If that is your point of view, then it could easily be your answer to kefeizhou 's answer. In any case, I agree with JNK that this question shouldn't be closed, as is a valid one.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that:

- Any reasonably query optimizer will be able to convert between “not exists”, “exists” and "joins", so there is normally no performance difference these days.
- “Not exists” can often be easier to read then joins.

Therefore I don’t consider “Not exists” to be bad practice in the general case.